# Returning json data from php to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get a json object from php so I can work with it in ajax. Here is my ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'get',
   url: eventsListPath,
   dataType : "json",
   data: {},
   success: function (data) {
       $('#eventInformation').html(data.table);
       alert(data.table);
   }
});
```

And my PHP:

```
$obj->table="hey";
echo json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

But the line

```
alert(data.table);
```

comes back with 'undefined'. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` in `success`. Tell me the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your php code. Json encode an array.

```
$obj['table']="hey";
echo json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Alternate - Or your class should be like this

```
class your_classname
{
  public $table;
 //other class related code
}
$obj = new your_classname;

$obj->table="hey";
echo json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: please do mark my answer as correct if the code helped you. thanks @Steven Jacks

Answer (score 1):

if I'm not mistaken, json_encode just works for arrays

```
$obj = [{table:"hey"}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->table="hey";
echo json_encode($obj)
```

produces

{"table":"hey"}

Check it using Firebug. Also check the content-type, should be `Content-Type: application/json`

Answer (score 0):

you must pass **array** to json_encode not object

```
<?php
$array['table'] = "hey";
echo json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```